# Validate zip code before placing the order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Without entering real zip code checkout won't allow placing the order. We need this for the UK site.

In detail: If the shipping country United Kingdom is selected then the customer need to insert a valid zip code like "AB2 3CD". They won't allow dummy zip code like "AB2"

Please check the attachment. Magento shows the notice, not an error. Customers can allow continuing without entering a valid post code.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community! I hope your time here is pleasant and productive. If I understand your question correctly, then Sergey Fedosimov may have already provided an answer for you here: [UK GB Post Code Zip Validation Magento 2 Space](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328276/uk-gb-post-code-zip-validation-magento-2-space). If this solves your problem, be sure to provide Sergey with an upvote by clicking the "up" arrow next to his answer to let others know that it helped you. This makes the community better for everyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replay and we have checked [UK GB Post Code Zip Validation Magento 2 Space](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328276/uk-gb-post-code-zip-validation-magento-2-space) this but is for warning message.
We don't want a changed the warning message but if we enter "AB12" then we can not proceed further. If we add "AB12 3CD" then we can proceed.
Thanks.